# Django sum of objects filtered by date view

Tags: python, django, date, view

I want to get sum of items i get by using generic date view.

Example views.py

```
class OrderDayArchiveView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.dates.DayArchiveView):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    date_field = 'date_ordered'
    template_name = 'ordersys/manager/archive_page.html'
```

Example template:

```
{% for order in object_list %}
    <li class="bg-light">
        {{ order.id }}: {{order.print_ordered_items_products_amounts}} (${{order.create_cost}}) 
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Example path in urls.py:

```
path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/', views.OrderDayArchiveView.as_view(month_format='%m'), name="archive_day"),
```

I want to get sum of all 'order.create_cost' sent to template, is it possible to get filtered queryset in this view? If not, how can i sum it in the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply override `get_context_data` and add your aggregation there:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

class OrderDayArchiveView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.dates.DayArchiveView):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    date_field = 'date_ordered'
    template_name = 'ordersys/manager/archive_page.html'
    
    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(object_list=object_list, **kwargs)
        queryset = context['object_list']
        sum_create_cost = queryset.aggregate(Sum('create_cost'))['create_cost__sum']
        context['sum_create_cost'] = sum_create_cost
        return context
```